# how to name variables and functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to find a way how to name variables and functions. Maybe you know a book or a good article how to name it? Or maybe you can help me to name variables and functions in next situations(all below is just examples):
1) function which checks that a car has a windows.
2) variable which stores a state. For example a state that save button must be disabled or must not.
3) functions which checks that save button must be disabled or must not.

Answer (score 2):

Well... that's what I call an easy answer.

You really don't have to think much about this. Just give the function a representative name that describes what it does and isn't easily repeated. Example:

1. carHasWindows()
2. isDisabled
3. isSaveDisabled()

what is recommended is that you name them in camelCase as most people do, and follow the rules of Js variable/functions names.

Comment: thanks. but what about second and third points? I mean is it normal that variable which stores button disabled state and and function which check that this button must be disabled or not, have the same name?

Comment: yes it is... but is up to you to see if that would create any confusion in your code. In doubt don't be afraid to use long names. That's good for you and many times avoid the need for longer method documentation in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it would be best to follow some form of standardised naming convention. This will make your code more maintainable and readable especially to other programmers, though  I guarantee you'll also thank yourself in a few years time when you try to go through some code you've written quite some time before ;)

http://www.j-io.org/Javascript-Naming_Conventions

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to keep variable names the same. If it's name in the database or backend code is `object_id` - because of standards like pep8 - then refer to it as `object_id` across all the code.  Including, but not limited to html & javascript.

However if it's just a javascript variable/function, then by all means use camelCase.

Who really wants to waste hours writing `object_id=objectId` on the backend when your `POST/GET/PUT/DELETE` could easily be `object_id`, and everyone reading the code will know beyond a shadow of a doubt that variable ends up on the backend.